# gprolog expert system - issues reading user input

Tags: prolog

I'm working through this prolog expert system example that accepts user input. I am having issues with the way user_input is read. I am using gprolog.

```
animal(dog) :-
  is_true('has fur'),
  is_true('says woof').
animal(cat) :-
  is_true('has fur'),
  is_true('says meow').
animal(duck) :-
  is_true('has feathers'),
  is_true('says quack').

is_true(Question) :-
  write('Does the animal have the following attribute: '),
  write(Question), write('? '),
  read_string(user_input,"\n","\r",End,Response), Response == "yes". /*this line*/

go:-
  animal(Animal),
  write('I guess that the animal is: '),
  write(Animal).
go:-
  write('I cannot recognize your animal').
```

I am getting:

```
uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,read_string/5),is_true/1)
```

It's the same error if I try:

```
read_string(user_input,"\n","\r",_,Response), Response == "yes".
```

Comment: Gprolog [doesn't seem](http://gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html) to have `read_string`/5.

Comment: This is tagged with SWI Prolog. What Prolog are you running?